# The Klein bottle and its Topology

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, klein-bottle

I have read in several places that the Klein bottle is a 2-manifold, but I cannot find an explicit proof anywhere.

How would you show it is locally Euclidean, Hausdorff and second countable (I think this is what defines something as a manifold...)?

And why can it not be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How has the Klein bottle been defined in the texts you've read? It is usually defined as a quotient of the closed unit square and the fact that it is a manifold follows shortly from that. Showing it cannot be embedded it into $\mathbb{R}^3$ is much more involved.

Comment: Okay, so the Klein bottle has been defined as: I^2 = {(x,y) : x, y are elements of I}. And I is defined as the interval [0,1]. The equivalence relations are : (x,y) ~ (y,x),  (0,y) ~ (1,y) ~ (0,y) and (x,0) ~ (1-x, 1) ~ (x,0).

Comment: @user367872 That's not correct (presumably $I=[0, 1]$); that's the definition of the unit square. The Klein bottle is a *quotient* of that.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was in the middle of writing my response and pressed enter before I finished.

Comment: take two möbius bands with boundary both, and identify their circle boundaries

Comment: Is there any way to show it is a 2-manifold just by using the quotient space of the square? Is it done by showing that the quotient space of the square is locally Euclidean, Hausdorff and second countable? Or am I way off?

Comment: Check out Lee's book "Introduction to Topological Manifolds". This is certainly somewhere in it.

Comment: Start here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294360/topology-on-klein-bottle?rq=1.

Answer (score 2):

The results you need in order to prove that the Klein bottle can't be embedded in $\mathbb{R^3}$:

$\bullet$ The Klein bottle isn't orientable.

$\bullet$ The Klein bottle is a compact, and connected 2-manifold.

$\bullet$ Any compact, connected manifold without boundary of dimension $n$ embedded in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ is orientable.

Therefore, the  Klein bottle can't be embedded in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: "Any compact, connected manifold of dimension n embedded in Rn+1 is orientable." I'm not sure about this method. We know that Möbius strip is a compact, connected 2-manifold embedded in $R^3$ and it is unorientable.

Comment: @BangTrangCong The Möbius strip has non-empy boundary, so is a "manifold with boundary", not a manifold.